Data pipeline from excel to excel in GCP
Have a question on the design in my project.
I just started working on an automation where an input excel file with 10 sheets is transformed to a new set of 15 sheets output file using vba macro. Currently the input and output files reside in a remote server.
Part of the plan is to move the input files to Google cloud storage, transform, and place the output files in another folder in GCS. The excel files can have 400k to 2 million records.
In this case, would Pandas dataframes be easier to implement or should I use openpyxl. Will there be an performance reduction in pandas?
I am in design phase and doing a PoC.

Python is a lot faster than VBA but you should write some code and tests yourself. You'll only know what's faster with your data.

Thanks for the input. What amount of data would help me to test the processing speed?

Sorry, questions like that aren't helpful. Time something in VBA and then try it in Python.

You could check out if sheet-excavator works for you. It can extract values from single cells, row patterns or columns. It is written in Rust so if you get it to work it is super fast. https://pypi.org/project/sheet-excavator/
